# How to make columns automatically flow to a row with Materialize?

Tags: grid, material-design, materialize

I have the following columns inside this row; however, I don't think they are floating correctly. Does a row need wrap every time there is 12 columns?

Is there a way to automatically flow in Materialize framework?

Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
  <div class="col s3">This div is 3-columns wide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you don't need to make a row every 12 columns, it should just fit it correctly. Could you post more details of how the layout is being rendered and what your expectations are?

Answer (score 0):

From their [docs](http://materializecss.com/grid.html):

> Remember when you are creating your layout that all columns must be contained inside a row...

Since their grid system uses the traditional 12-column model, this would be the max column size you would be able to fit in a single row.